# insert java check box value into sql

Tags: java, mysql, checkbox

Does anyone know how to insert the check box value into sql? All the check boxes value will correspond in one column of the field(Preferences) and will be inserted when the process button has clicked. 
The coding are as below:

**User.java**

```
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Process");
        btnNewButton.setBounds(360, 296, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton);
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                String place=null;
                String a=(String)comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String b=(String)comboBox_1.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String day=(String)comboBox_2.getSelectedItem().toString();

                if(chckbxLei.isSelected())
                {
                    place=String.valueOf(chckbxLei.getText());

                }
                if(chckbxAdv.isSelected())
                {
                    place=String.valueOf(chckbxAdv.getText());

                }
                if(chckbxHis.isSelected())
                {
                    place=String.valueOf(chckbxHis.getText());

                }
                if(chckbxOut.isSelected())
                {
                    place=String.valueOf(chckbxOut.getText());

                }
                if(chckbxFAK.isSelected())
                {
                    place=String.valueOf(chckbxFAK.getText());

                }
                Case ca= new Case();
                try {
                    ca.addPlace(a,b,day,place);
                    LoginGUI um= new LoginGUI();
                    um.setVisible(true);

                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }


    }       
    });
```

**Case.java**

```
 public void addPlace( String t, String k, String z,String h) throws Exception{

        DatabaseConnection db=new DatabaseConnection();
        Connection connect=db.getConnection();

        String sql="Insert into menu(Type,Budget,Day,Preferences)VALUES (?,?,?,?)";

        PreparedStatement ps=connect.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1,t);
        ps.setString(2,k);
        ps.setString(3,z);
        ps.setString(4,h);
        ps.executeUpdate();
        connect.close();
        ps.close();
    }
```

Everything working fine actually just I need some guidance on how to store multiple check box values in a single column in a MySQL DB. I really need help seriously . Your help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: what is the problem? don't you know how to get checkbox value or what?

Comment: I have 5 checkboxes and I want insert 3 checkbox values into sql. The problem is it insert only one checkbox value into sql

Comment: check box value means true or false ? right

Comment: is that web application? it's very unclear to me

Comment: Is it possible to add more than one check boxes value into sql?

Comment: yes it's possible .which are the columns you need to insert checkbox value? `Type,Budget,Day,Preferences`??

Comment: looks to me like t, k, z and ha are the values retrieved from check-boxes already, so the question is totally unrelated to check-boxes, as you already know how to get the values from them. for the actual problem you have, you should use a search engine with "Java SQL prepared statements".

Comment: I want insert checkbox values into Preferences @FastSnail

Comment: no...t k z will be inserted into sql also and they are drop down menu..only h is the checkbox values @hoijui

Comment: To make it more clearly, I have edited the post

Comment: @user5156075 how much columns exist in your table .are you asking to insert values more than 4 to table but you have only 4 columns ? and you change a single value `place` .if you want multiple value then you need multiple variables

Comment: There are 4 columns in my table. I want insert more than one values in the 4th column. (using check box)

Comment: @user5156075 you can but it's not recommended .read database  normalization

Comment: @FastSnail I already solved it..Thx ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It solved by using this way :)

```
 String valuesOfCheckBox = "";
  if (chckbxLei.isSelected()) {
  valuesOfCheckBox += chckbxLei.getText() + " ";
  }
  if (chckbxAdv.isSelected()) {
  valuesOfCheckBox += chckbxAdv.getText() + " ";
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for writing this answer. It was helpful. Can you please tell me what sql data type you used for the check box in your database?

Comment: Thanks! These codes worked fine for me and were helpful in my project!:-)